# Apple codes used in Applescript-able applications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

I read some examples of code necessary to make an application Applescript-able, but I still don't understand if the Apple codes used to identify a command, a class, a property can be any value I want (with the exception of the code for the application class), and if they must be registered in some site.

Is there a list of codes with a particular meaning for Applescript?

Comment: good to see developers still supporting applescript, Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want: [AppleScript Terminology and Apple Event Codes](http://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/applescript-terminology-and-apple-eve-nt-codes-e28094-developer-documentation.pdf). More can be found in [this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_creating_sdef/SAppsCreateSdef.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001979-BBCBCIJE).
Four-letter codes consisting solely of lower-case letters are reserved to Apple. Otherwise you're perfectly free to choose one.

You don't have to register them, as far as I know.

Comment: Damn Apple linkrot. The AppleScript Terminology and event codes doc is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I found a version of "AppleScript Terminology and Apple Event Codes" and updated the link in this answer. It may be important to note that the link leads to a WordPress site that doesn't seem to be owned or maintained by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Choose your own. They must be unique. There is no way to know if they are unique, but they must be.

Love it.